# GRUB: ELF sectors outside core

Tags: grub, xubuntu, boot, sectors

I just recently installed Xubuntu 12.04. Instantly after installing it I updated all my packages, however one package, `grub-pc`, failed to install. I'm not sure what caused it to fail, but here is the error:

```
bui@bluefly:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  hplip hplip-data libhpmud0 libsane-hpaio linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-hpijs
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
Setting up grub-pc (1.99-21ubuntu3.1) ...
cp: reading `/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2': Input/output error
cp: failed to extend `/boot/grub/unicode.pf2': Input/output error
dpkg: error processing grub-pc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
bui@bluefly:~$
```

I got worried and thought if I restarted my GRUB would fail to function. Unfortunately it did, and now I have this error:

```
error: ELF sectors outside core
grub rescue>
```

I'm stuck here and I'm not sure what steps to take. Advice would be appreciated. If it helps, here is a Boot Info Script log I took before restarting:

http://dpaste.org/hsssE/raw/

/dev/sda is my hard drive, /dev/sda1 is the partition Xubuntu is on. Thanks.

**Edit**: I ran `boot-repair`, however it failed, still giving me the same GRUB error.. Here's the output log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1119223/